# uncaught TypeError: ajaxForm is not a function in rails version 5?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I am trying to submit the modal form using ajaxForm and display the response in modal itself. But, I am getting uncaught type error (...).ajaxForm is not a function. 
Basically I want to create a modal form for lesson creation form and have to submit , my app consists of both API controller and front end controller.

```
    api!
  param_group :lesson
  description 'creates a lesson'
  example "
  {
    'id': 12,
    'title': 'MUDRAS',
    'active_video_id': 3,
    'description': 'Description of the lesson',
    'points': null,
    'is_public': '1',
    'videos': [
      {
        'video': {
           'id': 1,
           'video': {
              'url': '/uploads/video/video/1/250-authentication-from-scratch.mp4'
            },
           'title': null,
           'storage_type': 'Lesson',
           'storage_id': 12
        }
      },

    ]
  }"
  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
    @lesson.creator = current_user
    if @lesson.save
      render json: {
        success: true,
        message: "Lesson created Successfully"
      }
    else
      render json: { success: false, message: "Could not Create : #{@lesson.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}" }
    end
  end
def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end
```

The above code is my API controller.The below codes are my Front end controller and lesson related forms.

```
def create  
    @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
    if @lesson.save
      render json: {
        success: true,
        message: "Lesson Created Successfully"
      }
    else
      render json: {
        success: false,
        message: "Lesson Creation Failed"
      }
    end
  end
```

I need to display the "New Lesson" button in Lesson Index page.
lessons/index.html.erb

```
<% unless current_user.student? %>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-left">
      <div id="newLesson" class="lesson-category btn-danger" lesson_url="<%= new_lesson_path %>">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> ADD LESSON
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" id="newLessonForm">
    <% @lesson = Lesson.new ; @lesson.videos = [Video.new] %>
    <%= render "lessons/form" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "shared/primary_modal" %>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-left">
    <h2 class="main-tab tab-active">LESSONS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
      <h2 class="main-tab tab-inactive"><a id="responsesLink" class="blacko" href="#"><%= "MY" if current_user.student? %> RESPONSES</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12"><hr/></div>
  <!-- Lessons of this course Go here -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      <div id="lesson_<%= lesson.id %>" class="pill video-view lesson-load" data-lesson-id="<%= lesson.id %>" data-src="<%= lesson.active_video_url %>"><%= lesson.title %></div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- <div class="pill pill-inactive">Something</div> -->
  </div>

  <!-- Lesson Content goes here -->
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <%= render "shared/video_player" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lessonContent">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#newLesson").click(function(){
      var lesson_path = $(this).attr("lesson_url");
      $.get(
        lesson_path,
        function(content){
          $("#primaryModalContent").html(content);
          $("#format").val('js');
          $("#primaryModal").modal("show");
        }
      );
    });
</script>
```

My lesson creation form is given as a partial.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <%= simple_form_for @lesson, html: {class: "newLessonform"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Lesson Title", required: false %>
    <%= f.input :description, required: false, as: :text %>
    <%= f.input :points, required: false, as: :integer %>
    <%= f.input :is_public, label: 'Check to Make this lesson public', as: :boolean %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <% unless @lesson.new_record? or @lesson.active_video_url.blank? %>
        <h4> Currently Linked Video </h4>
        <video src="<%= @lesson.active_video_url %>" style="width: 400px;"></video>
      <% end %>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <h4>Add <%= @lesson.videos.blank? ? "a" : "another" %> Video</h4>
    <% @lesson.videos = [Video.new(title: "")] if @lesson.videos.blank? %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :videos do |g| %>
      <%= g.input :title, label: "Video title" %>
      <%= g.input :video, as: :file, lebel: "Select Video" %>
    <% end %>
    <center><%= f.submit class: "lesson-category btn-danger" %></center>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".newLessonform").ajaxForm(function(data) {
    $("#primaryModalContent").html(data.message);
  });
</script>
```

In the above script , I have given ajaxForm. The modal form for this is given below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="primaryModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" , data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h1 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row modal-body" id="primaryModalContent">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error in chrome console , was uncaught error:(...)$.ajaxForm is not a function.
I am stuck in this for about a week. Could any one give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are loading in the correct js library file, and doing so in the correct order, ie after jQuery library

Comment: Yea, I have added in the correct order Sir.

Comment: @ThananjayaChakravarthy the error message would suggest that you have not... $.ajaxForm is provided by this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ . It must be included in the page after jquery, but before you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use an AJAX form in rails is to use `rails_ujs`.

First you have to tell `rails_ujs` that you want an AJAX action on your form :

```
 <%= simple_form_for @lesson, html: {class: "newLessonform"}, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Then add a new file in your views, this view will be rendered after a successfull create action initiated by an AJAX action :  `views/lessons/create.js.erb`
Inside you can put you js code, this code will be executed on the same page as the AJAX form. This is just a view and you can use variables from the controller.

```
$("#primaryModalContent").html("<%= @message %>")
```

Finally, you need to update your controller to handle AJAX action :

```
def create  
  @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
  if @lesson.save
    @success = true
    @message = "Lesson Created Successfully"
  else
    @success = false,
    @message = "Lesson Creation Failed"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Here you can find some documentation about Rails UJS :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements 
https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/

Comment: Thanks a lot, for giving me a picture on using ajax in rails.

Comment: I have executed the code. But , error is showing as unknown format, pointing to "respond_to do |format|"